# Is there any way I can tell if a menu event has occurred using UIDocumentInteractionController?

Tags: ios, uidocumentinteraction

I've only just started in iOS development so bear with me. I'm building an app for a friend and one of the pieces of functionality is being able to post to Instagram a picture the user takes within the app. I have a `UIImageView` and a `UIView` (`vImagePreview`, the camera preview) in the same controller. What happens is, when a user takes a picture, the `UIImageView` is brought to the front and the image of the still picture is displayed in the `UIImageView`. There is a button in the `UIImageView` (postInstagram) that triggers the method to bring up the Instagram menu. I'd like to be able to bring the original view to the front when the user triggers either event in the menu (Open in Instagram or Cancel). Right now I'm using a timer and it does work but it's awkward. Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)postInstagram:(id)sender {

 //interactionControllerWithURL:instagramURL
 NSString *savePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/photo.igo"];

 //Write image to PNG
 [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image, 1.0) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];

 NSURL *photoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath];
 NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://user?username=USERNAME"];


 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
 self.docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:photoURL];
 self.docController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
 self.docController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Insert Caption here" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
 [self.docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
 timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 10.0 target:self selector:@selector(targetMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats: NO];


 }
}

-(void) targetMethod:(NSTimer *)timer {
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.vImagePreview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i am not fully understand your need. if I am not getting wrong

Just set `self.docController.delegate` to some  controller with UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate.

Then implement method and call that targetMethod in it:

```
documentInteractionController:willBeginSendingToApplication:
```

If it is not you want, just try others methods according to your need.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html